Find $m\in Q$ and $n\in Z$, for which the equality $m(19m+10)=143^n-2$ occurs.
The problem
Find $m\in Q$ and $n\in Z$, for which the equality $m(19m+10)=143^n-2$ occurs.
my idea
All I could think off is that we can note $m=\frac{a}{b}, (a,b)=1$ and get that
$m(19m+10)=\frac{a^2*19 +10ab}{b^2}=143^n-2\in N$ so $b^2| 19a+10b$
Also, we can write the equation as $19m^2+10m-143^n+2=0$ and apply the quadric formula but I don't think it would help...

If $b^2| 19a+10b$, then $b| 19a+10b$, and so $b| 19a$ ... now use $(a,b)=1$

@Sil Sooo...b is or 1 or 19

Yes, or $-1$, $-19$, i guess unless you assume $b>0$

@Sil My mistake... we dont know if b>0...but how is this going to help? , all we can do take some cases...

You introduced $a,b$ so you can assume $b>0$ and $a\in \mathbb{Z}$. Anyway I don't say it leads anywhere, it's just a possible continuation from your attempt.

Quadratic formula gives us $19m^2+10m-143^n+2=0$
$m =\frac {-10\pm \sqrt {100 + 4\cdot 19\cdot (143^n-2)}}{38}$
So we must have $100 + 4\cdot 19\cdot (143^n-2)= 4(25 + 19\cdot 143^n - 38)$ be a perfect square so
$19\cdot 143^n - 13$ must be a perfect square.
$19\cdot 143^n -13 = 19\cdot 11^n13^n-13 = 13(19\cdot 11^n 13^{n-1} -1)$ is a perfect square.
So we must have $13|19 \cdot 11^n\cdot 13^{n-1} -1$.  But that's impossible if $n-1 > 0$.  So we must have $n =1$ and $13|19\times 11 -1=208 = 16\cdot 13$
And as $16$ is a perfect square  we are done and confirmed!
Um.. wait.. where were we?
... restepping....
$100 +4\cdot 19\cdot (143 -2)=$
$ 4(25 + 19\cdot(143 - 2)=4(19\cdot 143 -13)=$
$4(19\cdot 11\cdot 13 -13)=4(208\cdot 13)=$
$4\cdot (16\cdot 13\cdot 13) = 8^2\cdot 13^2= (104)^2$
So $m =\frac {-10\pm 104}{38}=-\frac {57}{19}, \frac {47}{19}$ and $n=1$

Who comes up with these problems?!
